# access session users in models

Tags: python, django, models

Is There any possible way to access session users in models,
Iam override the save method in models which needs user to check role and then save,
And also using djangorestframework for apis which calls save method in models ,
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You would pass your save function the request object from one of your views.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        print request # this is the request object if it was passed into save()
        # do whatever you'd like with request here.
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def myview(request):
    MyModel.objects.save(request=request)
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply,in the above answer we need to call myview ,but in our situation djangorestframework calls save method of model, is there any other way to get session users without call view function, get users in model